# Moving from a R2 university to a R1 university

Tags: united-states, faculty-application, tenure-track, academic-life

I am currently negotiating a TT position with a R2 university. This is my first faculty job offer after 4 years of postdoc experience in ecology and biogeochemistry related area. My long-term goal is to land a TT position in a tier 1 and/or R1 university. To that end, is there any pros or con that I should know before signing the contract with a R2 university. Does this count against you if you are trying to apply for a R1 university after you served as a TT faculty in a R2 university?

Comment: "My long-term goal is to land a TT position in a tier 1 and/or R1 university."  Why?

Comment: Because I enjoy research more than teaching and want to have the hard money funding in my bucket too.

Comment: Could this question be edited to make it more accessible to international readers? I have no idea why "TT" is, and readers outside the US may not know what "R1" and "R2" is.

Answer (score 7):

Who can say how individuals would react, but I would find it preposterous if anyone counted it against you. Of course, the competition for such faculty positions is very fierce, so make sure that you build a record of accomplishment in your first job and build a strong "stable" of collaborators.

The difference between a given R1 and a given R2 can be quite small, and not consistent across fields. Do the best you can and you will be more likely to have the best career you can have. It is more up to you than to somewhat arbitrary and subjective designations.

It may take a while to move up, of course. And don't give colleagues the impression that you are unhappy or that you think you are "below your station".

Comment: Thanks Buffy for your thoughtful suggestions. One quick question is that should I focus more on building accomplishment that is expected from R1 universities (e.g. number of publications per year). Also, should my experience as a TT faculty in R2 be valued (or counted) when I apply for R1 job later on?

Comment: Do good research. Write a lot of papers, Find collaborators. Depending on the field, go to a lot of conferences. Yes. All of that. If you move prior to tenure some of your time may be counted, or not, depending on a lot of things. Sometimes it is actually and advantage to set the clock back. Othertimes no. It depends on your record at that point. And note that there are at least a few people who disagree with my advice, given the voting. I'm assuming they think you can only go down, never up, but they haven't revealed any reasons.

Comment: Thank you both. I am curious how "it is advantageous to set the clock back". I also thought about doing another prestigious postdoc, but also took a few steps back thinking that it may not look good on your CV if you are a eternal glorious postdoc. Another reason is that postdocs are not eligible to serve as PI for most of the federal grants. I feel like I'm ready to lead federal grant proposals and for that, I need a platform with a faculty tag. I also felt the need to have one or two federal grants on my CV to be competitive for academic jobs in R1 universities. Is this making any sense?

Comment: Since a tenure decision is final for that institution, if you are "moving up" to one with higher standards, it may make sense to give yourself more time to publish those all important papers. But it highly depends on individual circumstances. Sometimes good, other times not. It depends on your record and your trajectory.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the explanation!